# how to make nginx proxy pass read hosts domain mapping

Tags: nginx

I am define a domain mapping in `/etc/hosts`,this is my `/etc/hosts` config:

```
172.19.150.82 traefik.infvie.org
```

and this is my nginx proxy config:

```
proxy_pass http://traefik.infvie.org;
```

by default the ngnix not read `/etc/hosts` file and not redirect request to 172.19.150.82,how to make nginx using local hosts define domain mapping and not request from internet.Actually I am install treafik and need access by domain.What should I do to config nginx?

Comment: Have you reload the nginx server after your changes. [ sudo nginx -s reload ]

Comment: I am restart nginx like this: docker restart nginx@ArpitJain